# MySQL/Aurora increase column size behavior

Tags: mysql, ddl, aws-aurora

I would like to increase the size of a column.
The column currently is *varchar(1000)* and will be changed to *varchar(2000)*. Null value is already permitted.

The tables has about 2 millions of records, huge reads and many writes (less than reads).

MySQL/Aurora version = 5.7.mysql_aurora.2.09.3

1 - I wrote this command:

```
LOCK TABLES mytable WRITE;
ALTER TABLE mytable MODIFY COLUMN description VARCHAR(2000);
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

This command took about 4 minutes to complete.

2 - I wrote only this:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable MODIFY COLUMN description VARCHAR(2000);
```

This command took about 3 seconds to complete.

3 - I wrote this (just for testing purposes):

```
ALTER TABLE mytable MODIFY COLUMN description VARCHAR(50); -- Decreasing
```

This command took about 4 minutes to complete.

**Questions:**

I think that second option is faster because mysql will update only metadata, and "knows" that does not exists any record to check due that it is a increasing operation. Is it right?

I am searching for the best way to update this table without using strategies like copy to another table or another column.

Note: I tested in a separated instance (the same hardware) and simulate the same queries (read and write) for all wrote command.

**Edited:** Change MySQL Version

Comment: Modify your experiment queries and add ALGORITHM=INPLACE then look at the messages and warnings.

Answer (score 1):

- If you are using Engine=MyISAM, you should convert to InnoDB.
- With InnoDB, you probably don't need `LOCK TABLES`.
- Why not switch to `TEXT` (in this case)?
- For long-running `ALTERs`, consider using Percona's `pt-online-schema-change`.
- Increasing a `VARCHAR` is faster in new versions of MySQL (including, at least, 8.0)  It is faster because it is a "meta" change -- that is, the schema changes, but not the data.
- Decreasing a `VARCHAR` must go through all rows and truncate any rows with too much text.
- As a general rule, if the data has to change, `ALTER` must copy the table over.
- Altering the `PRIMARY KEY` requires restructuring the data's BTree, hence requiring a copy.
- Many changes to secondary indexes can be done in the background, so they appear to be instantaneous.

Comment: *Decreasing a VARCHAR must go through all rows and truncate any rows with too much text.* Also decreasing the length from 1000 to 50 should rewrite the table and move the column values from external string storage into the table body.

Comment: Sorry, the MySQL version I put was wrong, I have edit there. Do your comment apply to that version?

Comment: Minor addition: If the row size has to change, it requires a table copy. This can be true for example if you change the nullability of a column, even if you change nothing in the data.

Comment: @BillKarwin - Would changing _to_ `NOT NULL` cause setting to the `DEFAULT`?

Comment: @Akina - Good point.  However, depending on row format and the sizes of the columns, the Varchars may or may not actually be in "off-record".

Comment: @Akina, Not necessarily. A VARCHAR(1000) column allows long strings, but the values that are actually stored in the rows may be short enough that they are in fact stored on the main page for the row.

Comment: @javaTry - Most of the `ALTER` improvements were already in 5.7, so my answer does not change much(?).  There have been so many changes (mostly after 5.1) that I have not kept up with all the details.  Meanwhile, MariaDB is moving at a different pace.  Furthermore, I don't know if Aurora has any of its own changes.

Comment: @RickJames, Changing nullability, either to NOT NULL or to NULL, changes the length of the bit field indicating nullability per column. Both changes would cause a table restructure.

Comment: @BillKarwin True. If a string is short it is stored in the record body.

Comment: Could it be that NULLness is stored in the high-order bit of the length field?

Comment: I read this, so I think that will be in-place, I will test soon and tell you:
The number of length bytes required by a VARCHAR column must remain the same. For VARCHAR columns of 0 to 255 bytes in size, one length byte is required to encode the value. For VARCHAR columns of 256 bytes in size or more, two length bytes are required. As a result, in-place ALTER TABLE only supports increasing VARCHAR column size from 0 to 255 bytes, or from 256 bytes to a greater size.